# Windows Bootable USB with applications

Tags: windows-7, usb, bootable-media

Someone gave me a USB drive that is bootable into a Win 7 installation that also automatically installs antivirus and some other software. I can creat a bootable USB with an OS; I would like to know how to do the same but with the additional software installations? (Eg. Browser, antivirus, desktop shortcuts). Any ideas or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: its called Windows PE, how you create your own WinPE image, is well documented.

Comment: According to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx
WinPE is not for installation "Windows PE is not designed to be the primary operating system on a computer". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your question does not indicate you wanted this to be a primary operating system.  What exactly you were provided is not all that clear to be honest.

Comment: @Ramhound I apologize for my vagueness, I'm new to the environment and as a result would not know the exact terms. Let me try to be more plain. I would like to know if it is possible to create a boot USB / CD (Any media really) with an OS (Windows preferably) and other installations (eg antivirus, office ...) that I can use to install to multiple machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a website which is providing a useful service something what you want. 
[Ninite.com](http://ninite.com/)
 Scrolling a bit down you can tick programs from a list which you want to install. Then click on the "Get Installer" button. It generates you an executable which you have to download. After downloading it'll install all your selected softwares automatically. I don't know how complicated method you wanted, but this is easier way to do it rather than injecting them into a Win installer. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Can you run this off the USB stick without installing to the hard drive?